# Where does Rails ActiveRecord::Base define the hash constructor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, constructor

I know that objects in Rails that extend `ActiveRecord::Base` can use a constructor that takes a hash of attributes names to values, but I can't seem to find where that hash constructor is actually defined (doesn't seem to be directly in `ActiveRecord::Base`). Can anyone point me to where that constructor exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 3.2.7 the `initialize` method appears to be in [`ActiveRecord::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.7/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L464-502).

In the current master (commit `c10202208982bfa02ffd16d1614992228391d781` at time of writing), [`Base` includes `ActiveRecord::Model`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c10202208982bfa02ffd16d1614992228391d781/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L328), which in turn [includes `ActiveRecord::Core`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c10202208982bfa02ffd16d1614992228391d781/activerecord/lib/active_record/model.rb#L97), where [`initialize` is defined](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c10202208982bfa02ffd16d1614992228391d781/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L169-200). It appears to be very similar to the method in 3.2.7.

Comment: Yep, I was looking for the initialize method ActiveRecord::Core. Thanks.